# SQLite doesn't compile query - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have problems with SQLite function sqlite3_prepare_v2, it always returns 1 error code. I'm using SQLite wrapper SQLitemanagerforIOS4. Previously the same error happened without using the wrapper, I switched to it because, despite the statement was encoded in UTF8, the error still happened. I checked the database path with the debugger, and it's correct, so I'm lost...By the way, database is correctly opened and closed.

Here it is the pice of code :

```
- (NSArray *)getRowsForQuery:(NSString *)sql {

    NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

    if (db == nil) {
        [self openDatabase];
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;    
    const char *query = [sql UTF8String];
    int prepareStatus = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, NULL);


    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

Many thanks for your help.

Here they are the parameters passed to the wrapper object:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dbManager = [[SQLiteManager alloc] initWithDatabaseNamed:@"XLO.sqlite"];

    SArray *provinciaArray = [dbManager getRowsForQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT provincia FROM provincias;"]];
```

Thanks!

Peter, here it is:

```
- (NSError *) openDatabase {

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *databasePath = [self getDatabasePath];

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    #ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"SQL result: <%s>", dbpath );
    #endif

    int result = sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
            const char *errorMsg = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
            NSString *errorStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The database could not be opened: %@",[NSString stringWithCString:errorMsg encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            error = [self createDBErrorWithDescription:errorStr andCode:kDBFailAtOpen];
    }

    return error;
}
```

Many thanks to all!

Comment: What does your query look like?  Can you show code for preparing the parameters db and query?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with the code you requested . Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you print out sqlite3_errmsg(db) to your log to get more info on the error.

Comment: Can you provide your openDatabase method?

Comment: Hi all, following Alan instructions, I got this error: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  no such table: provinces, but the table is present in the database scheme for sure...

Comment: I updated the answer with the open database method. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's saying the database table does not exist, you may not be opening the database @ the path that you think you are.  Remember that sqlite is passive - it will create a database on first write.

Run the app in the simulator and print out the path.  Then go to that path in terminal and use the sqlite cmdline to confirm the db is there and it has the tables.

Comment: Hi all, The database was not in the correct path... Now it's working fine! Sorry and many thanks to all for your help.